# Unable to Connect with SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I'm creating a simple ASP.NET MVC 4 application using Entity Framework and code-first. With SQL Server Express 2012, everything works fine when using Windows Authentication:

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|myDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However, when using the following for SQL Server Authentication:

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|myDb.mdf;Integrated Security=False; User Id=mysa; Password=mysapassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I receive an error:

> "Login failed for user 'mysa'" ProviderIncompatibleException.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is your login setup to accept both types of authentication (SQL-Server and Windows)?

Comment: Can you connect to the server from SSMS using these credentials?

Comment: Did you provision the SQL login `mysa` on the LocalDB instance you're connecting to? Remember that each user gets a different LocalDB instance.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I'm new to LocalDB. I havent' done so, nor am I certain how to provision. I now realise that the user that I created in SSMS isn't for that LocalDB instance. My intent is to have the database available for each team member to work with during early development. Once the dust settles, we can then point to a permanent DB on a dedicated server. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your *.mdf file is not attached to sql server instance?

Try attaching the myDb.mdf file to your database with SQL Management Studio and the change the connection string to

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Category=myDb;Integrated Security=False; User=mysa; Password=mysapassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and don't forget to give the appropriate rights to your user